# I am trying to code a method that calculated the modulus and complex conjugate of complex numbers, but the = sign is giving an error

Tags: c++

There is one complex number, with real and imaginary parts, c.real and c.imag respectively.

The error is on the = in the "mod =" and "conjugate ="  saying `no operator "=" matches these operands`

It also says on "mod =" that "modulus operator =%" but I don't know where I would implement the %

```
using namespace std;

class complex {
public:
    double real, imag;
    complex() {
        real = 0; imag = 0;
    }
    complex(double r, double j) {
        real = r; imag = j;
    }


    complex mod(complex c) {
        complex mod; // modulus operator = %
        mod = sqrt(pow(c.real, 2) + pow(c.imag, 2));
        return mod;
    }

    complex conjugate(complex c) {
        complex conjugate;
        if (c.imag >= 0)
            conjugate = c.real - c.imag;
        else
            conjugate = c.real + c.imag;
        return conjugate;
    }

};
```

Comment: a complex number consists of a real part and an imaginary part. you are trying to assign a double-precision floating point number to a complex number. Apples and oranges...

Comment: @dandan78 Real numbers are a subset of complex numbers, and `std::complex<double>` allows assigning from `double`. OP's `complex` class probably doesn't have this assignment operator.

Comment: Your C++ compiler is telling you what the problem is. The shown code is trying to assign a `double` value to a `complex` object. No suitable overload exists. Which part of that, specifically, is unclear to you?

Comment: So can I not assign a double precision floating point number to a complex object?

Comment: best not to declare variables inside functions that have the same name as the function, as it's liable to confuse people (and possibly the compiler). you can just `return c.real - c.imag;`, etc.

Comment: Not unless you specifically tell your computer exactly how that should happen. You cannot just assign a double value to a random class. C++ does not work this way. If you want to do that, you need to implement an appropriate overloaded assignment operator. You will find more information on doing that in your C++ textbook.

Comment: @underscore_d oh okay, thank you

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry i started c++ pretty recently, thank you

Comment: This should be explained in the chapter in your C++ textbook that gives this practice problem. Which C++ textbook are you using?

Comment: The modulus of a complex number is a real number, not a complex number. It represents the distance from the number to the origin. And it is not related to the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) in any way. Learn about [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) before writing code.

Answer (score 0):

You should review your knowledge on complex numbers first, before trying to program it.
And also what it means to negate a number (you don't need to check the sign to change it).

```
complex conjugate(complex c) {
    return complex(c.real, -c.imag);
}
```

Having said that, just use `std::complex<double>` in `#include<complex>`, unless of course this is a homework problem.

Also from the comment in your code, you are violently confusing the modulus, (or absolute value or norm or `std::norm`) of a  complex number with modulo arithmetic of integer division (denoted `%` in C++).